# oracle CONNECT_BY_ROOT searching within a group

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy, connect-by

given is the following table

```
   KID   | CROSS_LINK |  KEY   | GROUP_KEY 
 --------|------------|--------|----------- 
  COR001 |            | 711768 |    336406 
  EXP001 |            | 740194 |    336406 
  POD002 | DPR002     | 712408 |    336406 
  POD003 | POD002     | 718445 |    336406 
  DPR001 |            | 711825 |    336406 
  TRC001 |            | 713773 |    336406 
  DPR002 |            | 712199 |    336406 
  POD001 | DPR001     | 712191 |    336406 
  POD004 | POD001     | 815174 |    336406 
  POD005 | POD003     | 815181 |    336406 
  POD002 | DPR001     | 478800 |    475873 
  POD005 | POD002     | 300266 |    475873 
  DPR001 |            | 300202 |    475873
```

my sql statement is

```
select level lvl, kid,  CONNECT_BY_ROOT CROSS_LINK  as father, key, group_key 
 from  t
start with CROSS_LINK is not null
CONNECT BY PRIOR  kid =  CROSS_LINK
order by  GROUP_KEY
```

you can treat CROSS_LINK like a father column.
My aim is to show all fathers (direct and indirect in the hierarchy) of a KID within a GROUP_KEY .

This query doesn't run within a GROUP_KEY in an isolated way. You can observe the problem  in the behaviour of the KID 'POD005'. In the following image, I have highlighted the wrong line.

[image: Problem in the line]

Comment: why not `CONNECT BY PRIOR  kid =  CROSS_LINK AND PRIOR group_key = group_key`?

Comment: This seems to work. I will check it again, and give my feedbak here. Thanks

Comment: OK... I thought maybe I was misunderstanding the question.  I'll add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition to your `CONNECT BY` clause to enforce that it only finds children in the same `GROUP_KEY` as the parent row.

```
select level lvl, kid,  CONNECT_BY_ROOT CROSS_LINK  as father, key, group_key 
from  t
start with CROSS_LINK is not null
CONNECT BY PRIOR  kid =  CROSS_LINK
AND PRIOR group_key = group_key
order by  GROUP_KEY
```